How to get everything between <h2> on a website?
I have this website: https://medicaldictionary.lib.umich.edu/
I am trying to take the information from this website and make into a table, e.g.
                term                                                                                                               defn
1   24-hour coverage            When many health plans or programs are combined into one plan that can cover someone for the whole day.
2          abatement         Remove or cover a dangerous material, such as lead or mercury, from water, paint, or air, or other places.
3 abdomen, abdominal                                                                                          Your belly or tummy area.
4            ability                                                                                              To able to or can do.
5           ablation To remove or destroy a body part or tissue. This can be done in many ways, including surgery, radiation, or drugs.

I scanned the source code for this website and identified the tags, and then tried to write the following:
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

scrape_website <- function(url) {
    webpage <- read_html(url)
    
    col1_content <- webpage %>%
        html_elements(".row.flex-start.cardHeader") %>%
        html_text2() %>%
        trimws()
    
    h2_content <- webpage %>%
        html_elements("h2") %>%
        html_text2() %>%
        trimws()
    
    col1 <- unique(c(col1_content, h2_content))
        iconset_content <- webpage %>%
        html_elements(".iconset") %>%
        html_text2() %>%
        trimws()
    
    def_content <- webpage %>%
        html_elements(".definitionParagraph") %>%
        html_text2() %>%
        trimws()
    
    col2 <- unique(c(iconset_content, def_content))
    
   
    max_length <- max(length(col1), length(col2))
    col1 <- c(col1, rep(NA, max_length - length(col1)))
    col2 <- c(col2, rep(NA, max_length - length(col2)))
    
    result_df <- data.frame(
        Header = col1,
        Content = col2,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    
    return(result_df)
}

When I call it:
url <- "https://medicaldictionary.lib.umich.edu/"  
result_table <- scrape_website(url)

I get an empty result:
                                            Header Content
1 Application by the University of Michigan Library    <NA>

Is there a way to fix this?

Everything is available in the json file here : https://medicaldictionary.lib.umich.edu/data.json . You can capture it from there
out <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://medicaldictionary.lib.umich.edu/data.json")
out$definitions


How did I know about the json file?
Because I have done some bit of scraping earlier so I know such data is mostly available already on the backend. You need to inspect the page and look at the incoming data for it.
